# Save string with a Long date to a field with datevalue(string)

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, type-conversion, regional-settings

I have a string variable `Ldatum` with a Long date ("28 mei 2023"). I want to save it into a datefield in a table. The datefield called `VDADatum` is date with long date notation in the field properties.

I use the function `Datavalue(Ldatum)`. I get the error

> types doesn't match

I use the following code

```
If Not rd.NoMatch Then 'record found
    rd.Edit
    rd!VDADatum = DateValue(Ldatum)
    rd.Update
end if
```

I get the error

> types doesn't match

I tried cdate.

Is it possible it has something to do with my region settings?

Comment: The calculation works for me. However, I am in U.S. and the month is May, not mei. So possibly language and/or date/time regional settings are issue.

Comment: It will work if 'mei' is your _local_ word for 'May' and Access is set up for your locale.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use datevalue  with month names since you end up with locale-dependent code. If you want to do this reliably, write a simple date parser yourself

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a long date ("28 mei 2023"), I copied a short ("28/5/2023) date into the field.

In the table the short date has automatically changed into a long date.